# activeCollab 3, Sub task time entering

Tags: activecollab

Does anyone know of a module for Activecollab 3.1 + that can allow entering of time for sub tasks, and also one that can do (TPS) reporting, per milestone/task/subtask and users, etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are not aware of a module that provides time tracking on subtask level. That feature was removed in activeCollab 3 (to simplify the system and clearly communicate what the main unit of work is). Please, track time on task level and provide any additional information as record summary.

Comment: Seems to be the case, maybe I need more of a reporting that all tasks within a milestone can be broken down, aka how many hours were spent doing this milestone, as of now it's not built in.

Comment: The answer above is correct answer to your question, even though that might not be the answer that you were looking for :) I doubt that there will be any movement toward time tracking on subtask level any time soon because that feature was officially retired with v3.